# Run subset unittests by matching test method names

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a test.py file which has all the tests under the TestClass.
It looks like this

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1a:
        ....
    def test_1b:
        ....
    def test_2a:
        ....
```

I know I can run certain tests with the `-p` label to match patterns but this requires each test in an individual .py file ?  the pattern matching command looks like this `python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "*_test.py"` I guess it matches all .py files with `_test` in the file name.

I wonder is that possible to do the same thing when all the tests are in the same .py file.
For example, I want to run test name with pattern `test_1*`

Answer (score -1):

IMO, writing all tests under one class in on py file is counterproductive.

Naturally, tests are supposed to be written relative to the file they tests, so for example, check popular libraries source code:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-nlp/tree/master/keras_nlp/tokenizers

```
tokenizer.py
tokenizer_test.py
```

This helps keep the file from becoming too long and harder to navigate.

Unless it's a small one-file application, spilt your tests.

Also you can test a single testcase using CLI, as per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface):

```bash
python -m unittest mypkg.tests.test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. The tests connect to remote databases and validate the data accuracy so the test file only has tests and also only needs to have tests.

Comment: The [CLI documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface) should help.

Comment: i think you misunderstood my meaning, my test file is the same format as tokenizer_test.py. I want to run certain tests under the test class in this file by matching the test method name patterns

Comment: `python -m unittest mypkg.tests.test_module.TestClass.test_method` then this is what you are looking for. Also check CLI documentation.